# how to deserialize an object having a parameterized constructor

Tags: java, serialization, constructor, parameterized

Hi I am trying to deserialize the following object.

```
public class Book extends Item implements Serializable {
public Boolean isBook;
public Boolean isBookch;

private String publicationPlace;

private String publisher;

private int edition;

private String pages;

private String article;

Book(String title, String author, String year)
{
super(title, author, year);
    isBook = false;
    isBookch = false;
    publicationPlace = " !!! Not Known !!! ";
    publisher = " !!! Not Known !!! ";
    edition = 1;
    pages = "!!! Not Known !!!";
    article = " !!! Not Known !!! ";
}
```

this is structure of the object and I am serailizing it as ....

```
openw("books.dat");
        Date date = new Date ();
        out.writeObject(date);
        for(Book b : books )
            out.writeObject ( b );
        closew();
```

and this is working pretty much working fine with out any errors.
I am tryin to decentralize it as ...

```
openr("books.dat");
        Date lastsaved = (Date)in.readObject();
        System.out.println("last saved date : " + lastsaved.toString());

        while( true )
        {
            Object o = in.readObject();
            if(o == null )
            break;
            else
            {
            addItem((Book)o);
            books.add((Book)o);
        }
        }
        closer();
```

and this is giving the error as : java.io.InvalidClassException: Book; no valid constructor

How to clear this problem.. thanx in advance...

Comment: A good explanation is available at

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7151711/java-why-doesnt-deserialization-invoke-constructor-whats-the-best-workaroun

Comment: `readObject()` returns `null` if you wrote a `null`: not otherwise. It throws `EOFException` at end of file, rather than returning a null. Breaking when you read a null is almost certainly incorrect and inadequate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The class `Item` must implement `Serializable` as well,

```
class Item implements Serializable {

    // ...

}
```

and it works!

If however, `Item` is out of your reach and does not have a non-argument constructor, you cannot make `Book` serializable. The only way to make a subclass of a non-serializable class serializable is if a *"subclass-accessible no-arg constructor of first non-serializable superclass"* is found (quoting from the source code of `ObjectStreamClass`'s `getSerializableConstructor` method). Which in your case seems to be missing, so `Book` cannot be made serializable.

In which case, given your object consists of primitives only anyway, you could to look into JSON as an alternative way of serializing objects. There’s a list of JSON libraries for Java on http://www.json.org

***NB,** how is it possible that Java can create objects of serializable classes without calling a constructor? There’s an unsafe method somewhere deep down in Java's API that is used to allocate objects without calling their constructor. True story.*

Comment: oh k thanx for the help.. but the item class is out of my scope and cant alter its code.. is there any other way...

Comment: 'A class without a non-arg constructor is only serializable if and only if all of its superclasses are serializable as well.' Nonsense. A class is serializable if it implements Serializable, directly or indirectly, and its nearest non-serializable base class has an accessible no-args constructor. The obvious counter-example to your statement is java.lang.Object, which is not Serializable, and which is the base class of every other class. Whether a class has or doesn't have a no-args constructor has no bearing whatsoever on whether it is serializable.

Comment: @EJP removed that sentence, better now?